# Can not get my resource-id of the public ip in azure

Tags: azure, kubernetes, fqdn

I want to deploy airflow in kubernetes.

To do that I am following this site: https://godatadriven.com/blog/deploying-apache-airflow-on-azure-kubernetes-service/

I have installed airflow. Now I am in FQDN with Ingress controller.

As the site recommends, I am following the guide of windows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-tls

with Nginx deployed in my kubernetes cluster I obtain the external IP and then I use these commands:

```
# Public IP address of your ingress controller
IP="MY_EXTERNAL_IP"

# Name to associate with public IP address
DNSNAME="demo-aks-ingress"

# Get the resource-id of the public ip
PUBLICIPID=$(az network public-ip list --query "[?ipAddress!=null]|[?contains(ipAddress, '$IP')].[id]" --output tsv)

# Update public ip address with DNS name
az network public-ip update --ids $PUBLICIPID --dns-name $DNSNAME

# Display the FQDN
az network public-ip show --ids $PUBLICIPID --query "[dnsSettings.fqdn]" --output tsv
```

but I receive this error:

```
az network public-ip update: error: argument --ids: expected at least one argument
```

because the environmental variable PUBLICIPID is empty. the query is not giving me anything.

why?

Comment: Do you add the external IP of the ingress correctly?

Comment: Any updates for the question? Do you solve the problem?

Comment: This is likely an issue with your permissions. As permissions in azure are an arcane art have your admin just try out the command and see if their get a result back.